# Solve the IVP $y''-2y'+y=e^t/(1+t^2)+3e^t$, where $y(0)=1$ and $y'(0)=-1$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I know the steps of this second order non homogenous but when solving $$y''-2y'+y=3e^t$$ you get while solving the exponential to equal $~0~$, $(0=3e^t)$.

How do you do this step?

Also how do you go about solving $$y''-2y'+y=\frac{e^t}{1+t^2}~.$$

Comment: Try $At^2e^t$ for the particular solution

Comment: I completed my answer Anonymous.

Answer (score 2):

For the particular solution, $3e^t$  method of undetermined coefficients can be used. Try $At^2e^t$.

Here is another approach:
$$y''-2y'+y=3e^t$$
$$y''-y'-(y'-y)=3e^{t}$$
$$e^{-t}(y''-y')-e^{-t}(y'-y)=3$$
$$(e^{-t}y')'-(e^{-t}y)'=3$$
$$(e^{-t}y)''=3$$
Integrate twice :
$$\implies e^{-t}y=\frac 3 2 t^2+C_1t+C_2$$
$$\implies y(x)_1=e^{t}\left (\frac 3 2 t^2+C_1t+C_2 \right )$$

**Edit** I didn't see your second question. We have :
$$(e^{-t}y_2)''=\frac 1 {t²+1}$$
Integrate 
$$(e^{-t}y_2)'=\arctan t + C_1$$
Integrate again
$$e^{-t}y_2=\int \arctan t dt + C_1t+C_2$$
You can evalute the integral by part
$$I=\int \arctan t dt=t \arctan t -\int \frac {tdt}{t^2+1}$$
$$I=t \arctan t -\frac 1 2\int \frac {2tdt}{t^2+1}$$
Substitute $u=t^2+1$
$$I=t \arctan t -\frac 1 2\ln|{t^2+1}|$$
Finally
$$y_2(t)=e^t\left (C_1t+C_2+t \arctan t -\frac 1 2\ln|{t^2+1}|  \right )$$
So the complete answer is:
$$y(t)=y_1(t)+y_2(t)$$
$$y(t)=e^t\left (C_1t+C_2+t \arctan t -\frac 1 2\ln|{t^2+1}| +\frac 3 2 t^2 \right )$$

Answer (score 0):

**Another approach:**

$$y''-2y'+y=\dfrac{e^t}{1+t^2}+3e^t$$
$$\implies (D^2-2D+1)y=\dfrac{e^t}{1+t^2}+3e^t\qquad \text{where $D\equiv\dfrac{d}{dt}$}$$
$$\implies (D-1)^2y=\dfrac{e^t}{1+t^2}+3e^t$$

Complementary function (C.F.) is $~C_1~e^t~+~C_2~t~e^t~$, where $~C_1,~C_2~$ are integrating constants.

Particular Integral (P.I.)

$$=\dfrac{1}{(D-1)^2} \left(\dfrac{e^t}{1+t^2}+3e^t\right)$$
$$=\dfrac{1}{(D-1)^2}~\left(\dfrac{e^t}{1+t^2}\right)~+~3~\dfrac{1}{(D-1)^2}~e^t$$
$$=e^t~\dfrac{1}{\{(D+1)-1\}^2}~\left(\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}\right)~+~3~e^t~\dfrac{1}{\{(D+1)-1\}^2}~1$$
$$=e^t~\dfrac{1}{D^2}~\left(\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}\right)~+~3~e^t~\dfrac{1}{D^2}~1$$
$$=e^t~\dfrac{1}{D}~\tan^{-1}t~+~\dfrac{3}{2}~t^2~e^t$$
$$=t~e^t~\tan^{-1}t~-\dfrac{1}{2}~e^t~\log{(t^2+1)}~+~\dfrac{3}{2}~t^2~e^t$$
Hence the general solution of the given  differential equation is $$y=\text{C.F.}+\text{P.I.}$$ 
$$y=~C_1~e^t~+~C_2~t~e^t~+~t~e^t~\tan^{-1}t~-\dfrac{1}{2}~e^t~\log{(t^2+1)}~+~\dfrac{3}{2}~t^2~e^t$$where $~C_1,~C_2~$ are integrating constants.

Now given that $~y(0)=1~$and$~y'(0)=-1~$. So $~C_1=1~$and$~C_2=-2~$

Hence the particular solution of the IVP is $$y=~e^t~-~2~t~e^t~+~t~e^t~\tan^{-1}t~-\dfrac{1}{2}~e^t~\log{(t^2+1)}~+~\dfrac{3}{2}~t^2~e^t$$

---

- $$\dfrac{1}{D^2}~1=\dfrac{1}{D}~t=\dfrac{1}{2}~t^2$$
- $$\dfrac{1}{D^2}~\left(\dfrac{1}{1+t^2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{D}~\tan^{-1}t=\int\tan^{-1}t~dt$$ $$=\tan^{-1}t\cdot\int ~dt-\int\left\{\dfrac{d}{dt}\tan^{-1}t\cdot\int ~dt\right\}dt$$
  $$=t~\tan^{-1}t~-~\int \dfrac{t}{1+t^2}$$
  $$=t~\tan^{-1}t~-~ \dfrac{1}{2}\log(1+t^2)$$